# Making products available on all sites by default

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, catalog, admin-panel, multicurrency

I have two Sites one for GBP and one for Euro but they are both using the same root category in the catalog.

First of all, is it possible to make new products visible by default in both stores when newly created, rather than having to tick the checkbox for both for each product.

Second of all, is it possible to edit the details for products for both store views at the same time, my products all use the default values from 'All Store Views' for everything except the price so I was trying to find a solution that would avoid the dropdown for each store view just editing the default values for all stores and just two boxes for price for £+€.

Any help or ideas for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be a better option to create a script using the API that updates products from say a spreadsheet or similar?

Comment: In order to achieve that, you will need to do some customizations. At native Magento is not possible

Answer (score 1):

All the stores by default using the 'Default Store View' value so here is the simple answer to your questions
1. Yes it is possible to have same visibility set with a single edit in Default store view
2. Yes it is possible to edit the details of products of both store view by editing it from Default store view

Comment: sorry maybe I didn't explain what I was trying to achieve properly. So on the admin side I want to make a fool proof way for non technical colleagues to add products, I don't want them to be able to see different store views, I want them to be able to add a product and add two prices for it in €+£ all on one page without ever having to switch views. I basically want to simplify the form to add new products so they can't mess anything up

Answer (score 1):

When you create a product by default it is assigned to all stores in same website. "Default store view" is the default setting for all the stores. If you want to edit the information of product just edit it on "default store view" and uncheck the "Use Default Value" checkbox on other store view.

Comment: I have two different Sites not just stores so I need to select which sites they are visible in. The issue is I want to edit the price (the one value that isn't default for both sites). What I am trying to achieve is a single page on the admin side without the need for the dropdown between storeviews where I can just add a product for all sites and have two input fields for price